# XSLT 2.0 separating two recursive outputs

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, tei

XSLT fiddle here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtqU/5

This question follows on from the implications of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52834795/xsl-2-0-generating-distinct-urls-from-nested-elements) where I wanted to output, using XSLT 2.0, `<persName>` into an HTML URL, where `<persName>` can be found inside another `<persName>`, so all are turned into URLs.

```
<persName nymRef="#Raimunda_Faure">Raimunda uxor 
   <persName nymRef="#Bernard_Faure_Senior">Bernardi Fabri 
                   senior</persName></persName>
```

Outputs to:

```
 <a href="www.foo.com/person/Raimunda_Faure">Raimunda 
    uxor</a><a href="www.foo.com/person/Bernard_Faure_Senior">Bernardi 
      Fabri<a>
```

Using the code found below. And I also use it for another 'named entity' that gets output to a URL, `<placeName>`.

The problem is that `<persName>` can appear inside `<placeName>` like so (and vice versa):

```
<placeName type="event_loc" nymRef="#home_of_Guilhem_Vidal">in domo 
    <persName nymRef="#Guilhem_Vidal_MSP-AU" role="own">Willelmi Vitalis</persName></placeName>
```

What I'd like is a separation of `<placeName>` and `<persName>`, such that they only create nested URLs where the same named entity type is nested inside a named entity.

Schematically, these would recursively output all `<placeName>` and `<persName>`:

```
 <persName>text
   <persName>text</persname>
   <persName>text</persname>
 </persName>

 <placeName>text
   <placeName>text</placename>
   <placeName>text</placename>
 </placeName>
```

But these would only output the parent entity as URL, whether `<placeName>` or `<persName>`, and bypass the named entities contained within them:

```
 <persName nymRef="#Raimunda_Faure">Raimunda
   <placeName nymRef="#Toulouse">Toulouse</placename>
   <placeName nymRef="Paris">Paris</placename>
 </persName>
```

Output to `<a href="www.foo.com/person/Raimunda_Faure">Raimunda Toulouse Paris</a>`

```
 <placeName nymRef="#Toulouse">Toulouse
   <persName nymRef="#Raimunda_Faure">Raimunda</persname>
   <persName nymRef="#Bernard_Faure">Bernard</persname>
 </placeName>
```

Output to `<a href="www.foo.com/place/Toulosue">Toulouse Raimunda Bernard</a>`

Here are the two existing templates:

```
<xsl:template match="tei:text//tei:persName">
    <xsl:variable name="nested" select="tei:persName[1]|
                     tei:persName[1]/following-sibling::node()" />
    <xsl:element name="a"> 
        <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="concat($paramPersonurl,substring-after(@nymRef,'#'))"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() except $nested" />
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$nested" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tei:text//tei:placeName">
    <xsl:variable name="nested" select="tei:placeName[1]|
                    tei:placeName[1]/following-sibling::node()" />
    <xsl:element name="a"> 
        <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="concat($paramPersonurl,substring-after(@nymRef,'#'))"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() except $nested" />
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$nested" />
</xsl:template>
```

It seems I should add an exclusion of the other named entity to either `<xsl:apply-templates select="node() except $nested" />` or `<xsl:apply-templates select="$nested" />` using something like `[node()[name() != 'persName']]`but I've not had success.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a template

```
<xsl:template match="tei:persName/tei:placeName | tei:placeName/tei:persName">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtqU/7

Comment: This seems to work, but in Oxygen Saxon-HE 9.6.0.7 reports a warning
: `Ambiguous rule match for /TEI/text[1]/body[1]/p[1]/seg[2]/placeName[1]/persName[1] Matches both "tei:persName/tei:placeName | tei:placeName/tei:persName"  and "tei:text//tei:persName" `

Comment: Put an explicit priority on the template you want to be used with preference, so I think you want to put e.g. `xsl:template match="tei:persName/tei:placeName | tei:placeName/tei:persName" priority="5"` on the template I suggested in the answer.